# Не происходит копирование папок из-за слишком длинного пути в Windows 10 Home. Редактирование значения с 0 на 1 в реестре не помогает

Tags: path

Не происходит копирование папок из-за слишком длинного пути в Windows 10 Home. Редактирование значения с 0 на 1 в реестре не помогает. Нужно именно настроить систему для работы с путями превышающими стандартное значение в 256 символов. Именно настроить для того, чтобы приложение которое я использую для бэкапа своих проектов на другой запасной SSD могло также без проблем копировать (делать бэкап). Смотрел в сети варианты, но пока ничего не нашел. Там вездн пишут про редактирование значения в реестре с 0 на 1. Оно не помогает. Какие сущестуют способы?

Comment: А в локальных групповых политиках копались? 'gpedit.msc' Конфигурация компьютера → Административные шаблоны → Система → Файловая система. Там вы увидите политику включения длинных путей Win32.

Comment: Думал, что групповой политики вообще нет в версии Home, а оказывается я неправильно в сети прочитал инструкцию, групповая политкиа есть, но нет ее версии GUI, а через реестр можно в нее зайти. Невнимательность моя. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: К сожалению способ с групповыми политиками через gpedit.msc не помог. Пути по прежнему ограничены в количестве символов. В сети даются инструкции по решению этой проблемы, но эти инструкции не работают. В чем проблема? Какокй смысл тогда в этих инструкциях, если они не решают проблему? Бред какой-то.

Comment: в винде всё немного магично (ни хрена не понятно как оно работает), есть как минимум 3 точки доступа: настройки, реестр и политики. И ещё множество точек отказа. В данном случае ПО может останавливаться из-за неизменямых запретов в Home версии (поможет только апгрейд или стороннее ПО, которое не спрашивает про этот запрет). ПО может использовать свой драйвер для доступа к файлам, ограниченный драйвером для DOS-версии (в винде много легаси всех выпусков вплоть до 1.0), так же официальные драйвера винды могут быть ограничены версией. Возможно проще настроить копирование из-под live-cd другой ОС.

Comment: Пришла шальная идея. Попробуйте поставить на винду Python с веб-сайта Python. В самом конце установки инсталлер предложит disable path length limit - вдруг автоматика сработает лучше всех ручных настроек?